# Elastic Beanstalk failed to update local Git configuration

Tags: django, linux, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Here's the error I'm getting:

> Failed to update local Git configuration. Follow the instructions at
>   "http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-get-started.html`"
>   to set up your Git repository, and then try again.

I've followed the directions on that site to the letter, to no avail.

EB exists on my path, and it gets most of the way through the process, but then it hits this at the end. It even succeeds in launching an EB instance. I've chmod'd my .git folder for write access, and the config file within there, but nothing seems to get rid of this error. I cannot do 'git aws.push' because git is not being configured to run this command.

I'm on Mac OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion). The folder is in `/var/django/mysite`. My folder looks like:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 robertferguson  staff   102 Jan  6 20:05 .ebextensions
drwxr-xr-x   4 root            staff   136 Jan  9 11:50 .elasticbeanstalk
drwxrwxr-x  10 robertferguson  staff   340 Jan  9 11:37 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 root            staff    18 Jan  9 11:37 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--@  1 robertferguson  staff   152 Jan  6 17:43 README.txt
... (all the django/site specific files)
```

This seems to be related to a permissions issue; I don't think django is related at all.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### See comment by Josh Davis below.

Comment: You should update to the [new CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-getting-set-up.html) that was just released last week. It is far better and you won't have this issue. Just install it with: `sudo pip install awsebcli`

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "git is not being configured to run this command." Can you type 'git' on the command line, or is git not configured at all? If the latter, you can add git to your `PATH` variable by following these instructions:

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/

This should allow you to use git in the command prompt - just type `git`.

Once that's done you can set up your AWSDevTools by downloading them from here:

http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk/6752709412171743

You already have the .elasticbeanstalk folder, so you may already have these installed? What is in your .elasticbeanstalk folder? (Don't post the contents of the file as it may be your AWS Keys, just let us know if it is or not.) If it is, skip to the last instruction. If it is not your keys, skip to the `git aws.config` line.

Then cd into your repository and run the Repo Setup:

`~/Downloads/elasticbeanstalk-cli/AWSDevTools/Linux/AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh`

Then do `git aws.config`, enter your access keys and app/environment for EB.

Then you can `git add .`, `git commit -m "commit message"`, and `git aws.push`.

Comment: I just finished figuring this out, and come back and you've answered it perfectly. (typo on 'repository and tun the Repo'). Thanks!

Comment: If you have trouble running the setup scripts on windows 8, you may need to install .NET framework 3.5 See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727702/cant-get-aws-elastic-beanstalk-command-line-tool-to-work-on-windows-8-get-the

Answer (score 1):

I had some of the same problems using their instructions and then one of the techs at AWS came back to me after asking in the Amazon forums and said that they were running into a few problems since switching to the python shell over from the Java/Ruby hybrid tool.

The instructions at that part had said to run:

```
sh {path}/AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh
```

But I found out that it worked if you used bash vs sh and then everything worked from there

```
bash {path}/AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me, but I've seen a couple other similar posts that were solved by this. I just had to go through and use 'git aws.config' since 'eb init' didn't complete the git configuration automatically.