# Can't get AWS Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Tool to work on Windows 8. Get the following PowerShell error?

Tags: asp.net, powershell, command-line, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

*Add-Type : Cannot add type due to the following exception: Compiler executable
file csc.exe cannot be found.. Verify that version 3.5 of the Microsoft .NET
Framework is installed. On 64-bit versions of Windows, the WOW64 component is
also required.
At C:\Users\Albert\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AWSDevTools\AWSDevTools.
ps1:315 char:1
+ Add-Type -Language CSharpVersion3 -TypeDefinition $awsSource
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Power
   Shell.Commands.AddTypeCommand*

**PATH set to** %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0\eb\windows;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

**I'm following [this tutorial online](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_symfony2.html)**

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install .NET 3.5 on your Windows 8 machine as it isn't installed by default.  Open up the Control Panel, select Programs then Program and Features.  Select the "Turn Windows Features on or off" link on the left and select .NET Framework 3.5 and press OK.

Comment: legend thanks! Was googleing my ass off trying to solve this.